# Why my game build resolution scaled the actual game view down

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, resolution, screen-resolution

When I play the game in the Unity editor the game is full screen, but after the build the game may be "full screen" but the actual game window is scaled down in the middle of the screen. How can I actually get the game to be full screen after the build?

I've tried changing the resolution but it doesn't change the scale of the game window.

I want the game to actually be full screen like in the Unity editor.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check out the `Edit > Player Settings > Resolution and Presentation`. You can change build resolution here.

You can also set full screen manually in the runtime using `Screen.fullScreen` (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-fullScreen.html)